# Finding Median of Dates in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, median

I am looking of a way to take the MEDIAN of a bunch of start and end dates (LOTS AND LOTS of dates). However, it would be specific to various "invoice numbers." See sample data below.

```
 invoice_no   invoice start date      invoice end date
 4006            11/14/2001               12/15/2004
 20071  11/29/2001               02/01/2003
 19893  11/30/2001               12/02/2001
 19894  11/30/2001               12/04/2001
 004             10/22/2002               10/31/2002
```

Find median between start and end date.

The median would just be whatever is between start and end date for that specific invoice_no. However, in an effort to filter data as much as possible. I realized I can also do WHERE STATUS <> 'REJECTED' and it should also help keep a lot of uncessary dates out. Also, I only wanted to filter between a few months so I added the BETWEEN DATETIME in as well.

Code so far:

```
  WITH
    tmp AS
    (
        SELECT invoice_no,
                invoice_start_date, invoice_end_date, check_date, status_code,
                cast(count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_no) as float) AS total,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_no ORDER BY invoice_start_date, invoice_end_date, check_date) AS rn
        FROM    INVOICE_HEADER INNER JOIN
                      INVOICE_HEADER_CUSTOM ON INVOICE_HEADER.invoice_id = INVOICE_HEADER_CUSTOM.invoice_id
```

```
                  WHERE status_code <> 'REJECTED' AND
```

Check_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-31 00:00:00', 102)
    )

`SELECT *
    FROM tmp
    WHERE (total / 2.0 - 1) < rn and rn < (total / 2.0 + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, only missed a `PARTITION BY` clause in your `count` statement.

```
WITH
    tmp AS
    (
        SELECT invoice_no,
                dates,
                cast(count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_no) as float) AS total,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_no ORDER BY dates) AS rn
        FROM    INVOICE_HEADER
    )


SELECT *
FROM tmp
WHERE (total / 2.0 - 1) < rn
    and rn < (total / 2.0 + 1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. So I made a mistake in my own work - there is actually an 'invoice_start_date' and 'invoice_end_date' - and am actually looking to find the median between those TWO dates. Same concept of the invoice_no still applies. I updated my original post too.

Comment: Sorry - I realize this sort of change is a big change to teh original question. And so, I created a new question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489691/finding-median-between-two-dates-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

I would express the median as:

```
SELECT invoice_no,
       (MIN(date) +
        (DATEDIFF(hour, MIN(DATE), MAX(DATE)) / 2.0)
       )
FROM (SELECT ih.invoice_no
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_no) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_no ORDER BY dates) as seqnum
      FROM INVOICE_HEADER ih
     ) ih
WHERE 2*seqnum in (cnt, cnt + 1, cnt + 2)
GROUP BY invoice_no
```

Most of this is probably self-explanatory.  You need the `partition by` to do the calculation for each invoice number.  You need the `order by dates` to put the values in the right order.  The `where` clause is my preferred method of handling the odd/even problem for the median.

The final step is a bit tricky.  When there are an even number of values, the median is the average of a date time.  That can be a bit hard to calculate.  Instead, take the minimum date and add the difference between the maximum and minimum.  This produces the average when there are an even number of elements.  This also produces the average when there are an odd number of elements, because the min and max are the same value.

Comment: How would I handle this sort of concept if there is an 'invoice_start_date' and 'invoice_end_date' It would be the same concept, but instead, taking the median between TWO dates. I've tried to incorporate both date fields into my SQL but to no avail. You can see my updated post above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1985793 . . . Changing the question from the median of one column to the median of two columns is a substantial change to the question and should be asked as another question.

Comment: Ah ok - sorry. Didn't want to repeat a question, but I suppose it is a pretty significant change. I will make a new question. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489691/finding-median-between-two-dates-sql-server-2008